# Best strategy for a "rush-victory"

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

**What I mean by rush victory?**

Win the game as fast as possible, without wasting any time on side-quests/other objectives.

---

[Based on this chart of tech tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgZPy.jpg) we can say that the "order" would be:

1. Start the game
2. Kill an Alien
3. Xeno-Biology TECH
4. Arc Thrower TECH
5. Arc Thrower WEAP
6. Capture an outsider
7. Ethereal Device TECH
8. Gallop Chamber
9. Psi-Armor TECH
10. Psi-Armor ARMOR

But, here are the problems:

1. It's hard to kill aliens without advanced tech.
2. It's hard to survive the aliens without advanced tech.
3. It's hard to collect resources (money) to build the necessary items.
4. It's hard to go to advanced missions with low rank soldiers.

---

What's the faster way to finish the game?

- Do I need to wait until full squad advancements + gear?
- Do I need to avoid losing countries?

PS: I know that with the gear and upgrades it's "easier" to do so.

Comment: its much easier to rush imo if you have the EW DLC, mimetic skin is OP

Comment: Just to add a link to your comment @z- [XCOM: Enemy Within](http://store.steampowered.com/news/11841/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of a "challenge" is to make it harder on yourself, or to see how much grinding you can skip and win on pure skill alone.

Here are the things you will **absolutely** need:

- Autopsy (unlock arc thrower project)
- Arc thrower designed and built
- Alien Containment built
- Live capture of Outsider via ARC thrower
- "interrogation" of outsider to detect alien ground base.
- Destruction of ground base, capturing ethereal comm device
- Sectoid Commander autopsy (unlock psi potential)
- Build psi lab and start testing soldiers for potential
- Hypercomm research
- Shoot down the overseer UFO (it *might* be possible for an interceptor with anti-air missiles to stay in range long enough for a kill if you burn through every single boost you've managed to create from captured alien corpses; if not, you'll need to segue into Alien Nav Comp, Alien Power Source, and New Fighter Craft to build the Firestorm)
- Research the Ethereal device
- Build Gollop Chamber
- Have one psi-active soldier wearing psi-armor and have them use the chamber
- Complete the temple mission.

As to your additional questions:

- You don't get a game-over until and unless eight countries drop out of the program.  Of course, losing a country means losing potential income and continent bonus, and by powering through everything as quickly as possible you'll likely be critically short on, well, everything, most of the time.
- You don't *need* to wait until you've got maxed out soldiers and the best possible gear, but while it is *theoretically* possible to beat the temple mission with just starting equipment, especially if you've done it before and know what's waiting for you at each juncture, expect it to be **brutally** hard.

> You'll be up against two Sectopods simultaneously in one chamber, for instance.

**EDIT** Come to think of it, I'd absolutely recommend playing the Slingshot DLC if you have it at all. It nets you a high level soldier and a *big* chunk of resources very early into the game if you succeed, and potentially lets you bypass a number of dangerous interceptions.

Comment: Nice answer! Two minor points: 1. Shooting down the overseer UFO using only boosts requires you to have done some autopsies to get the boosts. Probably less research effort than getting the Firestorm, but not research-free. 2. I'm pretty sure the psi soldier doesn't have to be at max rank; I think they get automatically promoted for the temple ship mission.

Comment: Great answer. I was thinking about the skills of my soldiers. If there is a good one that will help "prevent" kills. (as the sniper shoot at ally sight)

Comment: its definately not possible for an anti air missile interceptor to shoot down the overseer ufo on classic and higher difficulties.  I couldn't manage it even with all 3 boosts and plasma cannon.  The time is so short you have to do a ton of damage, and you won't get a second chance most of the time as the second interceptor will take too long to reach it if its no where near a base.

Comment: You don't actually need someone at max psi rank. They just need to be wearing psi armor.

Comment: On my last playthrought with classic difficulty I shot oversear ship down with interceptor. But I used EMP cannon it still required to resarch new fighter class. I think that with Fusion Lance it could also be possible to shoot oversear down with Interceptor. (using all BOOSTs)

Comment: Fusion Lances can't be put on a regular interceptor, though. Only Firestorms can mount them. Also, in EW, you need to interrogate a non-outsider alien as well. On the other hand, IIRC in EU you don't even need the Alien Containment. The Outsider Shard doesn't require Containment, and you don't need an interrogation to research the shard in EU. (That might've been patched; I haven't played EU since EW came out.)

Comment: @Nurkka Yeah, EMP requires the advanced flight research. And regardless of whether an Interceptor can mount it, you'd still have to 1) shoot down and recover a battleship (not a cakewalk by any means, even if you use the Slingshot DLC) and 2) research the Fusion Lance tech.

Comment: Also, you might as well remove "burn through every boost", as you can only use one of each type per interception.  Correct me if I'm wrong, preferably by telling me how to use more than one...

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can use more than one of each type if you select another one once the first has worn off. I've rarely needed them, though, so not 100% sure.